# Noun for [object of annoyance]

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word which can be used in the following sentence:

> My biggest [*annoyance*] with that is the diagrams are drawn lazily in that book.

Essentially I'm looking for a synonym for *annoyance* but a more natural one. The ones I found in dictionaries are not what I'm looking for.

I also thought of the word *hitch*, could that work?

Thank you!

Comment: Please give a full sentence. What is "that"/ "it"?

Comment: @fev i edited it!

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary? Questions that can be answered by looking in a dictionary are off-topic on this site.

Comment: @fev i understand, i have and i have found none that satisfied the expression which i was looking for. How would you say that you are annoyed but with the *biggest* stucture yourself?

Comment: Your question was closed so it cannot receive answers. You must explain the particularity of the term you are looking for in the body of the question, for it to be reopened. In your sentence any synonym of "annoyance" would be fine depending on the meaning you wish to convey. We cannot choose for you -that would be writing advice which again is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking of "pet peeve". In this case, I'd suggest ***peeve***. Lexico [defines](https://www.lexico.com/definition/peeve) it as:

> A cause of annoyance.

> > ‘another peeve of mine is these so called reality shows’

Comment: @Pete already gave this answer

Comment: @LordCommander Pete did not give an answer. Now that it is an answer his comment has been deleted. If you like this answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

A commonly used word for this is ***grouse***. Please check the example sentence in the dictionary entry which is very similar to yours.

> My biggest ***grouse*** with that is the diagrams are drawn lazily in
> that book.

Lexico:

> [**grouse<sup>2</sup>**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/grouse) *NOUN*
> A complaint or grumble.
>
> ‘our biggest grouse was about the noise of construction work’